# Проверка SMTP аутентификации в C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить на авторизацию почты пользователя через сокеты?

Или если имеется иной способ проверки на авторизацию пользователя. Вариант отправки тестового письма (на библиотеки System.Net) на смтп почтового сервера уже пробовал, но он не очень подходит.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Мне просто нужно что бы после того как пользователь вводит Логин и пароль, я могу проверить, является ли его Аккаунт почты действительным или нет .. и не отправлять тестовые сообщения просто проверить существует учетная запись или нет, что будет способствовать дальнейшей работе программы с пользователем или нет

Comment: <Не по теме>Вы хотите, что бы пользователь вам доверил логин и пароль от своей почты?</Не по теме>

Comment: Ну вообщем да. 
На примере, допустим, как регистрация на хеш коде, я могу как зарегистрироваться, так и как зайти через Аккаунт в контакте или google и т.д

Comment: Но так, чтобы не редиректила меня на страницы аккаунтов, а проверяла внутри (на сервере).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем ищем понравившеюся нам библиотеку POP3 Client in C#
например
[Reading Email using Pop3 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/pop3client.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx

далее не хитро обрабатываем в action

```
MailPOP3 pop3Connection = new MailPOP3();

            string err = pop3Connection.DoConnect(Pop3,
                                                  110,
                                                  userAccount.UserName,
                                                  userAccount.Password);
            if (err == null || err.Length == 0)

                eror = err;

            if (!err.StartsWith("+OK"))
            {
                pop3Connection.Quit();
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                pop3Connection.Quit();
                return RedirectToAction("EmailSender");
            }
```

где pop3 имя сервера допустим pop.mail.ru

Comment: Это годится, если прием почты (POP3) и ее отправка (SMTP) проводятся через один и тот же сервис аутентификации. В общем случае это не так.

Если не хотите возиться сами с SMTP AUTH (на уровне сокетов), то можете отправлять (через используемую SMTP библиотеку) тестовое письмо в свой тестовый почтовый ящик и тут же удалять его (это будет дополнительная проверка работоспособности).